# Oracle PL/SQL Why do we need Primary and Foreign Key in tables

Tags: sql

Why do we need to use Primary and Foreign keys in two tables, what is the benefit of using them?

Comment: You need to learn the very **basics** of relational database design - pick up a good textbook and go reading - come back when you have concrete questions that we can answer here (this one is **way too broad**)

Comment: maybe it will help : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primary keys are used to uniquely identify each record in a table. Foreign keys in a table uniquely identify a whole row in another table.